# VIM: how to show css/scss location?

Tags: css, vim, sass

Is there a way to see the full location in a CSS/SCSS file in VIM?

For example (scss syntax):

```
div.mydiv {
  ul {
    li {
      h2 {
       ...
      }
      p {
       ...-> cursor position
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will show (in a statusbar for example):

div.mydiv ul li p

-dan

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: As relatively new to vim I wanted to know if its possible. Seems its not (natively its not, also tried several plug-ins). Sorry if it seems like a feature request.